# Is there any Fix for child selector in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6

While using :first-child :last-child , in css its works fine in IE7, FF.

Is there any possible fix for this.

Use of Javascript is fine. If it works without javascript it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all,

Here is the javascript version which I finally used for this Solutions.

```
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li:last-child").addClass("last");
    $("ul li:first-child").addClass("first");

  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a semantic class name to ease your suffering in IE6. Something like:

```
  <ul>
    <li class="first">First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
    <li class="last">Last Item</li>
  </ul>
```

And then in your CSS use:

```
ul .first { color: #F00; }
ul .last { color: #00F; }
```

Comment: This is definitely a quick-fix solution where your child elements aren't changing much (or at all).

Comment: Nice solution without JS. quite smart. 
+1

Comment: this is not a solution, since, if you are using firts-child or last-child you most probably where not able to statically add a specific class

Answer (score 3):

There's an exact solution that doesn't require changes to your HTML.  Use Microsoft "Dynamic Styles".  Here's an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
tr td:first-child {font-weight:bold; background-color:green;}
tr td:last-child {background-color:orange;}
tr td {_font-weight:expression(this.previousSibling==null?'bold':'normal'); _background-color:expression(this.previousSibling==null?'lightgreen':(this.nextSibling==null?'orange':''));}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
 <tr><td>First</td><td>Second</td><td>Third</td><td>Last</td></tr>
 <tr><td>First</td><td>Second</td><td>Third</td><td>Last</td></tr>
 <tr><td>First</td><td>Second</td><td>Third</td><td>Last</td></tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Also see http://mauzon.com/pseudoclasses-first-child-and-last-child-for-ie6/ .

Answer (score 0):

A more generic library that fixes a bunch of IE inconsistencies is Dean Edwards' IE7: http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/