# How to get the first ClassB inside ClassA?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-selectors

how to acheive this with CSS 1.0 (IE 6.0):

```
.ClassA > .ClassB
{
...
}
```

to get the first ClassB inside ClassA?

Comment: Why do you need a CSS1 solution? This is 2011, not 1991. The CSS2.1 spec has already been finalized, and IE6 implements *some* of it, even if not `>` or `:first-child`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/982759/is-there-any-fix-for-child-selector-in-ie6

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to do. Why not have two class and apply both when needed.

Comment: @BoltClock, unfortunately large organisations still live in 2001 which was when IE 6.0 was released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this with a pure CSS solution that works in IE6. Your best bet is to modify the HTML and add an extra class, or an ID, to the first `.ClassB` element, then select that.

Comment: @thirtydot: Sadder are the people who still have to cater for IE6 today :(

Comment: @BoltClock, Sadder are the people who don't have to cater for IE6 but choose to do so anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.ClassA .ClassB:first-child
```

would match the first descendant of .ClassA that is of type .ClassB

Comment: Yeah but he wants a solution that works in IE6. Plus `:first-child` is not part of CSS1.

Comment: first-child is not supported in IE 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can match all elements and then negate other than first.

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pWN3Q/):

```
.classA > .classB {
background: black;
}
.classA > .classB + .classB,
.classA > .classB + * + .classB {
background: white;
}
```

---

```
<div class="classA">
    <p class="classB" >
        aaasda
    </p>
    <p class="classB" >
        aaasdb
    </p>
    <p class="other">
        Other Class
    </p>
    <p class="classB" >
        aaasdc
    </p>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/>
<div class="classA">
    <p class="otherFirst">
        other as first child
    </p>
    <p class="classB" >
        aaasda
    </p>
    <p class="classB" >
        aaasdb
    </p>
    <p class="other">
        Other Class
    </p>
    <p class="classB" >
        aaasdc
    </p>
</div>
```